# Manage git submodules

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

We are using github to manage our project.
In my project we have two modules one for front-end and one for back-end.

I have one git repo and I am going to push my back-end code in it. Now, I want to make a submodule in that repo and want to push front-end code in it.

Q-> Is it required to make a seperate git repo for front-end and then I have to link it my main repo by running below command ?

git submodule add gitRepoUrl /path/of/submodule

Q-> How can I make a folder of an existing git repo a submodule ?
(Do I have to make that folder a git repo first and then have to link it in main repo)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git submodules are by definition links to commit objects of a separate repository, so it is required to create an own repository for the part of the code you want to include as submodule.

In your situation, I would spend some thoughts on the layout. Is the front-end really a submodule of the back-end? This sounds unlikely.

As for the second question: You need to extract the folder into an own repository. There are [multiple](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/) [guides](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) on how to do that. Afterwards, you can include the newly created repository as submodule.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I know layout is little strange but its client requirements so I have to follow this.